# Command 'get' not found, but there are 18 similar ones

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, get, blockchain

I'm trying to start a private blockchain network as this answer says: 
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-ethereum-network

but when I run the
 `$ get --dev --ipcpath ~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc`
 
command the terminal output is 
`Command 'get' not found, but there are 18 similar ones.`

As i googled this issue, it seems that i have more than one (18) commands like get.

How should I find and use the one I need?

**EDIT**

running geth the output is `$: command not found`
but running: `geth version` the output is:
`Geth
Version: 1.8.13-stable
Git Commit: 225171a4bfcc16bd12a1906b1e0d43d0b18c353b
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.10.1
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/local/go`

Comment: The command is `geth`, not `get`

Comment: see edited answer please